# fseek vs rewind?

Tags: c, fopen, fseek

I have noticed two methods to return to the beginning of a file

```
FILE *fp = fopen("test.bin", "r")
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
rewind(fp);
```

and

```
FILE *fp = fopen("test.bin", "r")
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

What would be difference if any between these methods?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They are basically two different ways to accomplish the same thing: set the pointer to the beginning of the file. The only difference is that `rewind` also clears the error indicator.

If given the choice, you should use `fseek`. This is because `rewind` doesn't return an integer indicating whether the operation has succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

If `fseek()` returns success, it will also clear the end-of-file indicator, whereas `rewind()` does not do so