# Why my inner loop only run once?

Tags: c, loops, fgetc

**a.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i, counter=0;
    char c;

    FILE *file=fopen("a.txt","r");

    for (i = 0x41 ; i < 0x45; i++)
    {
        printf("%c(%x) ",i ,i);
        while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        {
            if (i == (char) c)
                counter++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", counter);
        counter=0;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

**a.txt**

```
AAABBBAAA
```

I don't understand why the `for` loop runs perfectly but the `while` loop only runs once.

The output looks like

[image]

Comment: maybe you need to `rewind`?

Comment: How did you determine that the `while` loop ran only once?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz probably by seeing the counter value.  (_I posted and deleted the same comment a while ago._) :)

Comment: Because after you read the file once you're now at the end of the file?

Comment: `rewind(file)` after while loop will do the job

Comment: http://ideone.com/A5e5zk

Answer (score 7):

Read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) for `fgetc()`, (*emphasis mine*)

> `fgetc()` reads the **next character from stream** and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or `EOF` on end of file or error.

So, once the `while` loop has run, it will exit once `fgetc()` returns `EOF` and it will keep returning `EOF` for all successive calls.

You need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the stream (using [`rewind()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) or [`fseek()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek)) to start over from the beginning.

That said,

- `fgetc()` returns an `int` and a `char` is too short to store *all* the possible return value (for example, `EOF` itself). Change the type of `c` to `int`.
- For a hosted environment, `int main()` should at least be `int main(void)` to conform to the standard.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).

Answer (score 3):

In the first run of the `for` loop, the whole file gets used up, and you never reset it.  So it will only successfully search for character `0x41`.

You need to do one of these two operations after the `while` loop:

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

rewind(file);
```

The first [is preferred because of better error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839025/fseek-vs-rewind).

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int i, counter=0;
    int c;

    FILE *file=fopen("a.txt","r");

    for (i = 0x41 ; i < 0x45; i++)
    {
        printf("%c(%x) ",i ,i);
        while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        {
            if (i == c) counter++;
        }
        rewind(file);
        printf("%d\n", counter);
        counter=0;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```