# Writing and Reading to a file in C

Tags: c

I wrote a program that first writes the data into structure,which is then written to a file using `fprint`function and then i again want that data to be displayed into the screen,for this purpose i used `fscanf` function however something is wrong,i cannot do any of those.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct student
{
int rollNo,intakeYear;
char name[20];
};

int main()
{
struct student s[2];
FILE *ptr;
ptr = fopen("student.txt","w+");
if(ptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Couldnot open the file");
    exit(1);
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the name of student\n");
    scanf("%s",s[i].name);
    printf("Enter the roll number\n");
    scanf("%d",&s[i].rollNo);
    printf("Enter the  intakeYear\n");
    scanf("%d",&s[i].intakeYear);
    fprintf(ptr,"%s%d%d",s[i].name,s[i].rollNo,s[i].intakeYear);
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
{
    fscanf(ptr,"%s%d%d",s[i].name,&s[i].rollNo,&s[i].intakeYear);
    printf("Name:%s",s[i].name);
    printf("Roll:%d\n",s[i].rollNo);
    printf("Intake Year:%d\n",s[i].intakeYear);
}
fclose(ptr);
return 0;
 }
```

I don't know whats wrong here,however if i remove the fscanf part of the code,the file gets created and data is written to it too.

Comment: Tip: Don't have instances of hard-coded numbers like `2` littered through your code. Use a `#define` or a variable instead, `const` if you can, so there's one point of control here.

Comment: You will need to reset the file position to the beginning of the file to be able to read the data you wrote. See [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/).

Comment: Don't forget than fprintf/fscsanf etc have return codes that you can check for errors.

Comment: Oh I should have used the `rewind` function

Comment: You should probably use fseek (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839025/fseek-vs-rewind#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=They%20are%20basically%20two%20different,choice%2C%20you%20should%20use%20fseek%20.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the file and writing to it, moving to the end of the file and then attempting to read it. You can use `fseek` or `rewind` functions and it may be a good idea to do so in some cases but in this case I would close the file after writing to it and reopen it for reading.